# Array static method

Tags: java

please tell me how to print out result from Array static method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(add(1, 2));
        String a = "Learn Java";
        System.out.println(test(a));
    }
    public static int add(int a, int b){
       return a + b;
    }
    public static String[] test(String a){
        return a.split("[ ]");
    }
```

if I print out "add", the result : 3
but when I print out "test", the result show hex number.

Comment: Is the question: how do I print out the values in an array of Strings?

Comment: First of all why is your split with `[]`, shouldn't it be `a.split(" ")`? The other thing is you are getting a string array return from method `test` and you should use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test(a)))` to print that array.

Comment: The hex number you get is the hash code of the array. Keep reading about Java !

Comment: use `System.out.println(test(a)[0]+" and "+test(a)[1]);` in the 4th line.